# How would you create a push function using on queue operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, stack, queue

I have created a stack and queue interface based on list. creating all the operations of queue from scratch . I’m using  only queue operation such as enqueue , dequeue , getfront etc.
How  would I create a push function .

```
class Stack(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1=Queue()
        self.s2=Queue()


def push(s,x):
    enqueue(s.s1,x)
```

```
qs = Stack()
    push(qs, "a")
    push(qs, "b")
    push(qs, "c")
```

```
output 

[a, b , c]
```

but since its stack , it should be

```
 [ c , b , a ]
```

how would i reverse the element inside the stack?

Comment: `deque` may be a good place to start https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).